# get href from php and use element in JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have `xyz.php` and working menu `<li>` elements. I need to get `href`from php use it in Java script for navigate away. So I have list of li tag and in code it's displaying one for example. Each li tag has unique `href`.

My question is: If I have select only one li elements from the list. I want to use that li's associated `href` in IF condition in JavaScript and ELSE part is multiple Li's selected. The code is working for else part. But, I am having issue with IF part.

I am not getting the `href` value from PHP. you can get 'href'from `$xyz['url']` in php.

```
xyz.php
   <div class="global-wrapper">
     <ul class="list">
       <li> 
         <a href="#" data-categoryid="<?php echo $xyz['url']; ?>" class="loadProducts"></a>
         <input id="retreat-<?php echo $xyz['api_id']; ?>" class="custom-check-input more-filter-experience" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $xyz['name']; ?>" data-home-location="<?php echo $xyz['api_id']; ?>">
         <label class="custom-check-label" for="retreat-<?php echo $xyz['api_id']; ?>"></label>
     </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Here, the java script code:

```
xyz.js
     if(retreatIdArray.length === 1  && exploreDate === undefined) {
         var categoryId = $('.global-wrapper').find('.loadProducts').attr('data-categoryid');;  

             window.location.href = "/categoryId";   // having issue
      } else{
             window.location.href = '/destination';
      }
```

Comment: I'm not understanding what you are saying is not working.  You are giving the href in the if part a static string.  Are you saying it is not going into the if logic and always going to the else logic?

Comment: @Taplar Thanks for the reply. IF case is not working and I just edited the question again. What should I use to get dynamic equivalent href for each <li>.  Let me know, if you are still unclear.

Comment: Ok, so from what you've provided, it is not clear where `retreatIdArray` is coming from.  Also setting `window.location.href` inside an each doesn't make sense.  The first change will cause the page to navigate away from the page.

Comment: Yeah you are right, that does not make sense. Intially, it's retreatIdArray = [ ].

Comment: @Taplar thanks for your help. I want to pass the value of `data-categoryid` from php to javscript(`window.location.href`). I am still using static url for navigate away. Any suggestions please?

Comment: There is no server php issue here.  If you want a tag attribute value you need to explore the DOM.  Use console.log(categoryId) to see what you have.  Also, the browser console should help you (F12).

Comment: Thanks! In `console.log(catagoryId)` is displaying correct value and but it Navigated to URL: to this `xyz.com/catagoryID` and looking into it.

Comment: So you assigned the desired value to a variable.  You know how to _use_ a variable, right?  That's all you need to do.  Hint: you don't put the name of the variable in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote `undefine` instead of `undefined`. The statement inside `if` will never be true.

Also, to check for `undefined`, it's better to use `typeof`.

```
if(retreatIdArray.length === 1 && typeof exploreDate == 'undefined') {
    retreats = $('.global_wrapper').find('.custom-check-input').val();
    window.location.href = '/href';
} else {
    window.location.href = '/destination';
}
```

Note: untested code, you may have to adjust it to your needs. Please let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks, I have used undefined in my code. That's not an issue. The else condition works well. it's just if part does not work. I am not getting the actual value for href